# TFS 2017 - Build Agent Connection Error - Failed to Connect

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

We have a 3 tier TFS environment: 1 application server, 1 build server and 1 DB Server.  TFS 2017 is installed and configured.  We are attempting to connect the Build server with the Application server using config.cmd but receive the following error:

PS D:\agent01> .\config.cmd

> > Connect:

Enter server URL > https://tfs.domain.com
Enter authentication type (press enter for Integrated) >
Connecting to server ...
**An error occurred while sending the request.
Failed to connect.**  Try again or ctrl-c to quit

Firewall Settings:

Source: TFS Build Server
Destination: TFS Application Server
Ports: 443 and 8080

What other ports need to be allowed between servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reimported the wildcard certificate and I imported DigiCert High Assurance CA in Trusted Root on both TFS Build and Application server.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using https as your public TFS url.

Please **make sure you have created the Self Signed Certificate over TFS server and installed the same over build agent machine**.

More details take a look at this similar issue here: [TFS Build Agent Fails to Configure & Run with TFS2018 Self-Signed SSL Certificate](https://www.benday.com/2017/12/21/tfs-build-agent-fails-to-configure-with-tfs2018-self-signed-ssl-certificate/)

If you still have the same error after above actions, then please give a try with below steps which may help to narrow down the issue:

- Make sure you add the user running the installation of agent, to the
  pool and queue administrators
- Try to use PAT if you are using username/passwoard
- Temporarily turn off the firewall and try again

Comment: I created a self-signed ssl cert on the TFS Application server, imported it into the TFS Build server under Trusted Root and changed the URL binding for https to the self-signed cert (previously using wildcard cert).  I reran config.cmd and now see "Register Agent" after connecting to server.....

Comment: However, when I go to the URL - tfs.domain.com in Edge or Chrome I see:

Your connection isn't private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from tfs.domain.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards).
NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

tfs.domain.com uses encryption to protect your information. When Microsoft Edge tried to connect to tfs.domain.com this time, the website sent back unusual and incorrect credentials. This may happen when an attacker is trying to pretend to be tfs.domain.com, or a Wi-Fi sign-in screen has interrupted the connection.

Comment: Your information is still secure because Microsoft Edge stopped the connection before any data was exchanged.

You can't visit tfs.domain.com right now because the website uses HSTS. Network errors and attacks are usually temporary, so this page will probably work later.

Comment: Running the site in Private window shows:

Your connection isn't private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from tfs.domain.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards).
NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

This server couldn't prove that it's tfs.domain.com; its security certificate does not specify Subject Alternative Names. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.

Continue to tfs.domain.com (unsafe) - Clicking continue loads the site.

Comment: Note:  The URL loads without warning in IE11.

Comment: I followed instructions at https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/clear-hsts-settings-chrome-firefox/ regarding HSTS settings.

Going to the URL in Chrome and Edge now show:

Your connection isn't private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from tfs.domain.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards).
NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

This server couldn't prove that it's tfs.domain.com; its security certificate does not specify Subject Alternative Names. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.

Comment: Continue to tfs.domain.com (unsafe) - Clicking continue loads the site.

How do I stop the above message from displaying?

Comment: Hi @C1TonyB Thanks for your detail information. According to your comments, looks like a HTTPS security warning in lower Internet Explorer version. It should  not be  a TFS side issue. Kindly check if this works:  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_7/how-to-disable-the-https-security-warning-in/883d2fd8-f397-4ed6-86b5-e64997148a98 If not, you could try more ways in google or directly connect your IT admin to check this.